# What is the relation between validation_data and validation_split in Keras' fit function?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, keras

`validation_split` says: "*hey give me all the input data – I will take care of splitting between test and validation*".

```
model.fit(inputX, inputY, validation_split=0.20, epochs=10, batch_size=10)
```

`validation_data` says "*please give me explicitly the validation data*"

```
model.fit(inputX, inputY, validation_data=(testX,testY), epochs=10, batch_size=10)
```

Is there any hidden trick or something I am missing apart from my understanding?

Answer (score 7):

No, everything is correct. One potential reason behind this separation is that sometimes people have training and validation data separately (in many academic datasets) and sometimes you have all the data and can split it anyway you want.

Answer (score 4):

Your understanding is correct. To add more details - 
**v*alidation_split*** keras function makes easy for the user to split the training dataset into train and validation (saving your custom efforts).

For example - setting ***validation_split=0.2***, tells keras to use last 20% of the data before shuffling for validation.

Comment: so if you use validation split does it take the last 20 percent and fix it or does it keep changing the validation data from epoch to epoch?

Comment: @AmitLohani This depends on the value of your _shuffle_ parameter of the [.fit](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit) method. If set to _true_ (default), tensorflow will shuffle the dataset before each iteration and then assign the validation set portion. It seems like, tensorflow is trying to mimic a _k_-Fold cross validation behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

I will just add something important when dealing with unbalanced datasets. Using ***validation_split*** does not preserve the percentage of each class. Often, you will do your own ***validation_data*** so you keep those percentages.
Moreover, I would recommend [StratifiedShuffleSplit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html#sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit) to do so.

Comment: Are you affiliated to the site?

Comment: Hi, just saw your comment and no I am not. I have just been using this on many projects.

Answer (score 1):

If you use validation_data option, you need to prepare the validataion data and train data seperately, which would take more energy to do. Afterwards, the validation_split option allows you to merely input whole bunch of data and split it inside. Somehow, it is better to save time.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, but there's a minor mistake here,

"hey give me all the input data – I will take care of splitting between test and validation"

should be:

"hey give me all the input data – I will take care of splitting between **train** and **validation**"

Because it actually splits your dataset into two parts; **Train dataset** and **Validation dataset**.

And in the end, you use your test set to calculate the score of your model.